# App rejected by supposedly missing usage descriptions

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

When trying to upload my app to Appstore, my app gets rejected with this message:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   **NSCalendarsUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

the same happens with `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, and `NSCameraUsageDescription`.

I've used localized strings for all of these keys in `InfoPlist.strings`, but the build is still rejected. I'm using CocoaPods. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You must add  `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` to info.plist, just like doing before `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `NSCameraUsageDescription`

Comment: I did it. I added the three of them in the infoPlist.strings, but they are still not showing when launching the application.
Actually I'm not even using the camera, there must be a library or pod installation causing this.

Comment: Did you try real device?

Comment: Yup. And it never asked any of the requested permissions. Not even when deleting the app and installing again. It only asked for Push Notifications and Location (which I also have in my `InfoPlist.strings`). I tried placing them in the Info.plist source file and it keeps being rejected :(